# Android CheckBoxPreference Default Value

Tags: android, default-value, checkboxpreference

I have the following XML code for my `CheckBoxPreference`:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_boot_startup"
    android:title="Auto start"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
```

But when I retrieve the preference in code the value is `false`.

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean autoStart = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pref_boot_startup", true);
```

My `autoStart` variable returns `false`.

Is there a specific reason for this? Am I missing a step to set the default value to `true`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to set the defaults first:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate()
    {
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean autoStart = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("pref_boot_startup", true);

     {...}
    }
```

Comment: Note: I put this in a class that extends Application, NOT an activity

Comment: @MobileMon good shout! I was about to put it in a PreferenceFragment. Why though? :)

Comment: What purpose does the default value in the xml serve if I have to programmatically code it?

Answer (score 12):

Use junkdog's method, but for what it's worth, this is a bug in Android:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6641

Answer (score 3):

```
    // These two lines are working around an android bug:
    // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6641
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(REFRESH_COUNTER_PREF, prefs.getBoolean(REFRESH_COUNTER_PREF, true)).commit();
```