# Android PreferenceActivity checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, preferenceactivity

I am trying to get a checkbox to default to True when the app is launched.
I used this answer [Android CheckBoxPreference Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907830/android-checkboxpreference-default-value) but it still defaults to false and prints False in LogCat.

Any ideas where I have messed up? I've been looking at this for hours... thanks in advance!

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.layout.preferences, true);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean autoStart = prefs.getBoolean("checkBox1", true);

        System.out.println(autoStart);

    }

}
```

XML class:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <PreferenceCategory
   android:summary="Username and password information"
   android:title="User request" >
  <CheckBoxPreference
     android:key="checkBox1"
     android:title="request details" 
     android:defaultValue="true"/>

 </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Put `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean ("checkBox1", true).commit();` (use `.apply()` instead of commit if on 4.0+) above `SharedPreferences prefs = ...` and see if now you get true. Using `setDefaultValues` does not overwrite the SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your main activity you could do following:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFERENCES_KEY",false);
    boolean isSetToTrue = prefs.getBoolean("YOUR_BOOLEAN_KEY",false);

    if(isSetToTrue==false){

         //here set your checkBox to true
     }
```

main Activity means the activity that starts first with starting app.