# Checkbox always unchecked (no matter what is the default value)

Tags: java, android

Here i have my preferences in xml folder. No matter what I set as "defaultValue" I always get visually unchecked box, when I open my preference activity. Is this some kind of bug?

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <CheckBoxPreference 
     android:title="Enabled" 
     android:defaultValue="true" 
     android:key="checkbox_enabled_disabled"/>   

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Take a look at this question for a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3907830/804773

Comment: i already saw that answer, but it seems it's not working for me. I actually copy/paste the code and it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Inside You `PreferenceActivity` subclass you can fire following code.

```
checkboxPref=(CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("myPreference");
checkboxPref.setChecked(true);
```

This is just one of the approach.basically you will have to handle logic to not execute this code when user manually unchecked the preference.

Comment: Wouldn't that always force it checked when the Preference Activity is loaded regardless of the user's actual preference?

Comment: So there is NO way, to get working this using only XML code? So this IS really a bug?

Comment: The link suggested by @TheCapn should work.Don't know why it is failing in your case.

Answer (score 0):

actually, this bug was already fixed. I'm just being an idiot (or eclipse)

The thing is that when i installed application on emulator it really loaded default value. (The one that i defined in XML ) Then i changed it (in emulator). So then i put some more code in program and then i ran it again, but the thing is that previous value that i changed was still stored in emulator, even if i updated and i ran application from eclipse. That's why i was always getting up with false value (i left it false in program).