# How to get the default value from XML ( not working )

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

When starting service i need to check for particular setting ( boolean ). Please check following code:

XML Code:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Enable Sleep" android:defaultValue="false" android:key="checkbox_preference"/>
```

Java Code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean sleepEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("checkbox_preference", true);
```

if(sleepEnabled) {

// Code

}

Even tho, default value in XML is "false" i got "true" on every service start. I know this is because I'm setting parameter in "getBoolean()" method to "true", but I need there the actual value of checkbox ..

Why Am I getting always "true" when starting service?

p.s If i go to Settings and change the value of checkbox it's fine. Then when starting service again it pulls the actual value. So how to get the actual DEFAULT value set in XML?

Comment: what happens when you pass false in getBoolean?

Comment: I get false. But I'm not getting "natural" false from XML, but only because of java code. If you know what I mean..

Comment: and if you check the checkbox in your application, does it return true?

Comment: Yes. If i check it returns true, if i uncheck it returns false. It's working great.

Comment: I'm a little confused at this moment. SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean sleepEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("checkbox_preference", true);

The second parameter "true" is there only if the preference does not exist, but it does or at least it should. Why Am I'm not getting false instead ( becasue i declared false in XML ). I'm very confused about this atm..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android CheckBoxPreference Default Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907830/android-checkboxpreference-default-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
boolean sleepEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("checkbox_preference", true);
```

to this:

```
boolean sleepEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("checkbox_preference", false);
```

and take a look at the documentation:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:defaultValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3adefaultValue)